# Can't seem to make mysqli_insert_id work

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to make this work for a few hours and can't seem to make anything of it. The code I am using is below. I am working on a phpbb page, which explains the template and the sql query setup.

```
$sql_query = 'INSERT INTO ' . rosters . ' ' . $db->sql_build_array('INSERT', $sql_rost);
$result_rost = $db->sql_query($sql_query);

$roster_last = $mysqli->insert_id;

 $template->assign_block_vars('some_block', array(
    'ROSTER'    => $roster_last,
    'TEST' =>'test'
));
$db->sql_freeresult($result_rost);
```

The insert query works because I see the new entry in the database, and on the template I used the TEST to make sure that block is showing up, which it is.

Also, I didn't use

```
mysqli_insert_id($link)
```

because I am connected to the database with another snippet of code so I don't want to replicate a database connection. Without the `$link` I get an error that `mysqli_insert_id` is expecting another parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can use mysql to make a query, and then use mysqli to get the ID. 
Try this:

```
$db->insert_id;
```

Edit: Just noticed you said you are working with phpbb.
The phpbb wiki suggests the following:

```
$db->sql_nextid();
```

Source: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Database_Abstraction_Layer

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I just tried this and no luck.

Comment: I edited my post. Try this, and if it doesnt work look up the wiki for more information.